# "https://chat.askubuntu.com/" invalid security certificate

Tags: bug, chat, ssl, askubuntu

I recently found out from [here](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) that there is a `https://chat.askubuntu.com/` site, however when I try to go there I get this:

[image: Invalid security certificate in use]

So I thought I should just report that here. My browser is Firefox 47.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a separate site (or it is, but doesn't carry any useful information) - as you may know, it redirects to the set of rooms under https://chat.stackexchange.com, [more specifically](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=created&host=askubuntu.com). So I don't think it's a major problem, since the cert is valid for https://chat.stackexchange.com (the page tells that you).